# How to get geolocation using getRecord to show the mapMarkers?

Tags: lightning-web-components, geolocation

pokemonLocation.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card  title={cardTitle}>
        <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers} > </lightning-map>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

pokemonLocation.js

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const NAME = 'Pokemon__c'
const LATITUDE = 'Pokemon__c.Geolocation__Latitude__s'
const LONGITUDE = 'Pokemon__c.Geolocation__Longitude__s'

const pokemonField = [NAME,LATITUDE, LONGITUDE];
export default class PokemonLocation extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @track mapMarkers =[]
    name;
    cardTitle;
    //Using wire method  to get record it
    @wire(getRecord,{recordId: '$recordId', fields:pokemonField })
    getPokemons({  data, error}){
               
         if(data){
            this.name = getFieldValue(data, NAME)
            this.cardTitle = this.name;
            
            const Latitude = getFieldValue(data, LATITUDE)
            const Longitude = getFieldValue(data, LONGITUDE)
            
            this.mapMarkers =[{
                location: {Latitude, Longitude},
                title: this.name,
                description: `Co-ords: ${Latitude} ${Longitude}`
            }]
               }
        
        else if(error){
            console.log("THIS IS YOUR ERROR "+ error);
        }
    console.log("Dance " +NAME);
    console.log("Data => " + JSON.stringify(this.mapMarkers));

    }
}
```

ISSUE: The output is not showing the mapMarkers as it is somehow empty and I don't know why. Your help is appreciatd. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `NAME` variable seems incomplete: it only has the name of your object, it's missing the field name. It should be `Pokemon__c.Name` or something similar.
This is likely causing an issue with the `@wire` call to `getRecord`.